# How can I create a direct link to a bug in TFS web portal without knowing the project name?

Tags: tfs, bug-tracking

We use TFS web acces extensively, at the moment using TFS 2012.2.

Most workitem URLs on the website are built up as follows:

> http://{TFS-SERVER}:8080/tfs/{PROJECT-COLLECTION}/{PROJECT}/_workitems#_a=edit&id={WORKITEM-ID}

However, WORKITEM-IDs in TFS are independent from PROJECTs. So my question is:
Is there a way to create a direct link to a workitem by only knowing the WORKITEM-ID? For example, I would like to do:

> http://{TFS-SERVER}:8080/tfs/{PROJECT-COLLECTION}/workitemid={WORKITEM-ID}

Is this possible? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you actually tried? Because the format you're proposing just works almost as-is. (tested in TFS 2013 update 4).

Comment: http://jessehouwing:8080/tfs/DemoCollection/_workitems/edit/196

Comment: I tried a few things yes, but none of them is working. Neither is your suggestion unfortunately. Do I have to enable it somewhere?

Comment: Upgrade to TFS 2013 I suspect...

Comment: hi @jessehouwing can you add this as an answer so I can give you credit for it? :-) it seems you are right and works as expected in TFS2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS 2013 supports this through the following format:

```
http://{server}:{port}/tfs/{Collection}/_workitems/edit/{id}
```

But it seems that this was not yet enabled in Team Foundation Server 2012.